# Cocospod how to ignore single pod when use pod update?

Tags: cocoapods

When we use `pod update`, cocospod will update all pod of podfile.Also we can use `pod update frameworkname1` to update only `frameworkname1`.However, if i want to also dont update `framework1`，I have to use `pod update framework2,framework3,framework4,.....`. Any way can do like `pod update -ignore framework1` this?

Comment: Hi man, did you solve your problem? I also asked on github but didn't get right answer: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7334